# LINQ - Sum depending on multiple conditions

Tags: .net, entity-framework, linq

I want to create a linq query that will sum up a total of customer orders. Depending on what customer have already ordered I need to apply a diffrent multipler depending on product type. For example, Customer has ordered one SaaS and two PaaS products. For every PaaS product in that order I want to multiply a Price by 1.5, and for SaaS the price will be multiplied by 0.8.

Right now I have a code, that will give me total sum, regardless of the product the product. How can I write a query, that will sum up products for each customer depending on type of the product that customer have ordered? I also want this to be in a form of a dictionary, so for each ID I will have a sum of all orders.

Here is a little bit of code that I've prepared, for better understanding:

```
    public class Calculator
    {
        public void Calculate()
        {           
            // Let's pretend that customers comes from some sort of DB context
            IDictionary<int, decimal> totalls = customers
                .ToDictionary(c => c.ID, c => c.OrderItems.Sum(oi => oi.PriceNet));

            foreach (KeyValuePair<int, decimal> item in totalls)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{item.Key} {item.Value}");
            }
        }
    }

    public class Order
    {
        public Customer Customer { get; set; }
        public ICollection<OrderItem> OrderItems { get; set; }

        public Order()
        {
            this.OrderItems = new List<OrderItem>();
        }
    }

    public class OrderItem
    {
        public Customer Customer { get; set; }
        public Order Order { get; set; }
        public decimal PriceNet { get; set; }
        public Product Product { get; set; }
    }

    public class Customer
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Order> Orders { get; set; }
        public ICollection<OrderItem> OrderItems { get; set; }

        public Customer()
        {
            this.Orders = new List<Order>();
            this.OrderItems = new List<OrderItem>();
        }
    }

    public class Product
    {
        public EnumProductType Type { get; set; }
    }

    public enum EnumProductType
    {
        SAAS,
        PAAS
    }
```

Comment: You will need to use `AsEnumerable` to switch to LINQ to Objects and write a method to compute the correct price for `OrderItems`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this:

```
var totalls = customers.ToDictionary(customer => customer.ID, customer => customer.OrderItems.Sum(oi => oi.Product.Type == EnumProductType.PAAS
                ? oi.PriceNet * 1.5m
                : oi.PriceNet * 0.8m));
```

So, please modify your `Calculator::Calculate` method with below:

```
public class Calculator
{
    public void Calculate()
    {           
        // Let's pretend that customers comes from some sort of DB context
        /*IDictionary<int, decimal> totalls = customers
            .ToDictionary(c => c.ID, c => c.OrderItems.Sum(oi => oi.PriceNet));*/

        var totalls = customers.ToDictionary(customer => customer.ID, customer => customer.OrderItems.Sum(oi => oi.Product.Type == EnumProductType.PAAS
                ? oi.PriceNet * 1.5m
                : oi.PriceNet * 0.8m));

        foreach (KeyValuePair<int, decimal> item in totalls)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{item.Key} {item.Value}");
        }
    }
}
```